# Attempted to Repair GRUB through live USB. Has not worked, cannot get into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

Made a post earlier here: [Installed Windows 8.1 over 7. Can't Get into Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795230/installed-windows-8-1-over-7-cant-get-into-ubuntu-14-04)

Essentially, Had Windows 7 on my system first, as is recommended. Afterwards, Ubuntu was installed. Now after installing Windows 8.1 over 7, I can no longer get into Ubuntu. Windows is on one SSD, Ubuntu on the other. Old post was marked as a duplicate as such a question was asked and answered previously.

[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I followed the instructions to the tee here, yet I am still unable to get GRUB back up, therefore I cannot get back into Ubuntu. I could really use the help as Ubuntu is where all my personal and work related files are kept.

Edit / Update 7.22.16
These are the results I receive when I attempt to reinstall grub through the command line, as it's been suggested through many of the other solutions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGlZB.jpg

Comment: Try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) it may help

Comment: @chj1axr0 That seems like an actual app. As i'm unable to connect to the internet using the Live USB, i'll try and see if I can download Boot Repair and copy it to a USB

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following questions and answers:

- [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)
- [Dual Boot with Windows 8 UEFI - Ubuntu/GRUB Being Bypassed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321988/dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi-ubuntu-grub-being-bypassed)
- [Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)

In particular, try EasyUEFI, referenced in my answer to the first question, from Windows.

If these tools don't work, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I have attempted to use Boot Repair, as well as follow the instructions of those answers. As I attempted to install (re-install) Grub from the Boot Repair Live Disk, this is the result I got. In fact, this is the result I've been getting every time I've tried to use to command line to install grub. https://imgur.com/Umhi8Hz